# currently with Xcode12.3 Beta + iOS14.4Beta not supported to run

Tags: xcode

I am trying to run automation using Xcode 12.3Beta on iOS14.4Beta, but I am getting an error that says not supported. Any news on when apple will release Xcode12.4Beta or did anyone found a workaround for this issue?

Comment: what kind of automation tool were you using?

Comment: XCUITest framework